# Equivalent distances

Tags: metric-spaces

I am interested in the following property about distances: Given two distances $d_1$ and $d_2$,
$$
d_1(x,y_1) < d_1(x,y_2) \Leftrightarrow d_2(x,y_1) < d_2(x,y_2).
$$

Under my point of view, this could be a reasonable definition of equivalent distances. I suppose it has been studied but I do not find it in the literature. Could someone give me some information on it?

Regards,

Outis

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 references:

[Topological equivalence of metrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29#Equivalence_of_metrics)
[Topologically equivalent metrics](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Topologically_Equivalent_Metrics)

Comment: Dear Peter, thank you for your prompt reply. According to the first reference, $d$ and $\min(d,1)$ are equivalent. But, if we consider in $R$ the metrics $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_2(x,y)=\min(|x-y|,1)$ the condition is not satisfied: $2=d_1(3,5) < d_1(3,6)=3$, but $d_2(3,5) = d_2(3,6)=1$.